# Performance of Oracle xpath: two select scenarios

Tags: java, performance, oracle, xpath, xstream

I am using oracle 11g and have a table with an XMLType.  There are many records in this table and each XML contains a list of 0 to n answers as follows:

```
<section>
  <answer id="100">
    <value>Something</value>
  </answer>
  ...
</section>
```

There are two ways to xpath for values.

Example 1:

```
extract(table.column, '//answer[@id=100]').getStringVal()
```

which returns

```
<answer id="100">
  <value>Something</value>
</answer>
```

Example 2:

```
extractvalue(table.column, '//answer[@id=100]/value/text()')
```

which returns

```
Something
```

There is a hit in performance extracting many text() values for a complex query, which has me asking the following question.  Would I gain better performance if I utilized a library like xstream to parse out those values in java (example 1), or is it better to let oracle parse those values for me (example 2)?

I am trying to learn from other people's experiences or maybe some whitepapers before I commit time to rewrite a lot of daos and queries, so anything is much appreciated, thanks!

================== EDIT

Started looking into using Scala as an alternative to parsing xml in the JVM. Feel free to add Scala examples to the mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got around to testing and here is what I found.

For a simple "reporting" jsp view using a table, I ran a query to populate 850 rows.

Given my codebase, I ran the query first as follows:

- Query contained 3 left joins on XMLTypes for each record.
- Each record extracted 15 "Example 2" values.
- Each value did not need XStream processing.

This took a total of:

> **8.27 seconds** to run the query alone.
>
> **15 seconds** total to go from start to a finished view

I then altered the query to do following:

- Query contained 3 left joins on XMLTypes for each record.
- Each record extracted 15 "Example 1" values.
- Each value also ran XStream processing to extract value(s).

This took a total of:

> **24.84 seconds** to run the query alone.
>
> **60 seconds** total to go from start to a finished view.

This is of course my codebase, but I think I can rule out the use of XStream as a mean of efficiency.  But it seems that the XMLType and xpathing is not very efficient in the first place.

Comment: You may want to look into XMLType indexing: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_indexing.htm#CHDEADIH

Answer (score 1):

I suppose Example 2 should be faster.
If you need more more speed, I recommend to do normalization for this table and get rid from XML or use materialized view.